# Ubuntu 18.04 installation/upgrade freezes

Tags: boot, system-installation, upgrade, freeze

I have been tirelessly trying to install Ubuntu-18.04 since the last 2 days, but every attempt turned out to be negative. Apart from other GUI based problems, which I am reporting here.

When mounting the ISO using the inbuilt Disk Image Mounter utility, and attempting the GUI base upgrade method (from within Ubuntu-16.04.1).

**I get a pop-up saying**

> Oops! There was a problem running this software.
>   Unable to locate the program.

When mounting the ISO and attempting an upgrade through the terminal, the `gksu sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade` command leads to a blurred screen prompting for the password and then does nothing. Replacing `gksu` with `sudo` returns `cdromupgrade command not found`.

When booting from a live flash drive (created from the same ISO), the installation freezes at the network page after I enter the password for my wifi. When using a wired connection, the network page does not appear. The installation freezes at the page where it asks for Normal or Minimal installation. It even has options for Install Updates and install Third-Party Drivers etc (the 3rd page of the installation). I have tried different combinations of options, but the installation never proceeds further. Sometimes, it even freezes at the keyboard selection page (the 2nd page of the setup).

I have already verified the integrity of the downloaded ISO through a checksum verification. It is perfectly OK.

Current OS: Ubuntu-16.04.1 (latest kernel, as per `apt-get`)
Machine   : MSI GV62 7RD

Comment: Did you use the alternate installer ISO?

Comment: @Eranda Peiris: Thank you very much for the edit.

Comment: @David Foerster: I am not sure what you mean by the alternate installer ISO. I downloaded the 64-bit desktop version from ubuntu.com via torrent.

Comment: Then you didn't use the *alternate installer* (which is now the same as the [*server installer*](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/)) as recommended by the [accepted answer](/a/39108/175814) to my linked question. The *desktop installer* doesn't include the `cdromupgrade` program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I own MSI GS73VR 6RF. Even I had the same problem. But I was able to fix it by applying nomodeset during the boot from the liveCD.  Complete explanation is given in

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Try from the second step.( Step - press e)